# Rack in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

I have gone through various tutorials but concept of Rack is not clear to me.
I understand the node,datacenter,cluster.
Node stores the data.
DataCenter is collection of node.
cluster contains data.

Where does rack comes in the hierarchy. Please explain RACkS.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Nodes (Server) are stored in the RACK (physical Racks).
So each datacenter can have multiple racks and while placing the replicas cassandra will take care that your replica are alternated between the racks.

Comment: Does rack can contain more than one node. Why it is important to alternate replicas in rack.

Comment: yes.rack may contain more than one node. since we assume that rak will be physical there are chances that complete rack may go down because all the servers are attached to single switch in a rack. though some rack have dual power supply, some might have only one